# how do i solve this algorithm question(about dp and recursion maybe)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Here is the code challenge:

> A restaurant has  tables, each table can contain  people,  teams come to eat, and each team has  people.
>
> You can choose to serve or turn away a certain group. If you do not serve the group, the cost is . If you do serve this group, then one table might not seat everyone, so they may need to sit at separate tables,
> and the cost will be (−1), where  is the number of groups the team separated into.
>
> A table can only be used by one team. Please calculate **the least cost**.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> m  n  x  y
> 5  2  5  3
>
> a[] = {4,5,1,1,1}
> b[] = {7,3}
> output：6
> ```
>
> #### Explanation:
>
> The second team sits at the first table, the first team sits at 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup> tables, and the cost is (3-1)*3=6

I have tried a lot times. First of all, I think this is a dynamic programming question. But I couldn't conclude the state transfer function and the example is not an optimal substructure it seems.  So I tried to solve it by recursion, and calculate all the possibilities, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: which programming language you perfer ? i may try solve it later .

Comment: java or c++,thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There is no known general and efficient solution to this problem.  Not even a pseudo-efficient solution like dynamic programming.

That can be seen by reducing a special case of the [3-partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) to this one.  Given `3*m` numbers summing to `m*T` with each number of size between `T/4` and `T/2`, we set `x=1`, `y=4`, make the numbers into our tables, and have `m` groups of size `T` to seat.  If there is a 3-partition of the set, the optimal solution will be to seat every group at 3 tables.  (Why?  Because no 2 tables are big enough to seat a group.  So a 3-partition seats all groups optimally, and any seating of that cost is a 3-partition.)  Therefore a solver for your problem is able to solve this special case of the 3-partition problem.

But this special case is [strongly NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness).  Which means that not only is it NP complete, but it doesn't even have a pseudo-polynomial solution that dynamic programming would give us.

I would personally solve this problem in practice by viewing it as a [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  With a cost that I'd use a pair of numbers for, `(cost, -groups_left)`.  Even with a bad heuristic of the cost being 0 you can solve this greedily if a greedy solution is optimal.  And with some work on a smart heuristic, this likely will perform well in practice.

That said, there will be pathological cases where it takes exponential time and memory to finish.

Comment: than you very much, i sovle this problem by bfs but i know this not the best solution,cause i dont know how to define the next point to visit so i dont know how to apply A* search

Answer (score 0):

i try to solve it as follows :

- make all permutations of tables
- calculate all combination with mixing team & table order sequence.
- sort by cost by ascending.

hope it can help you.

```
import java.util.* ;

public class TableAllotment {
  static class Table {
    int idx, numOfSeat ;
    Table(int idx, int numOfSeat) {
      this.idx = idx ;
      this.numOfSeat = numOfSeat ;
    }
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("t(%d:%d)", idx+1, numOfSeat) ;
    }
  }
  static class Team implements Cloneable, Comparable<Team> {
    int idx, numOfPerson ;
    ArrayList<Table> tables ;
    Team(int idx, int numOfPerson) {
      this.idx = idx ;
      this.numOfPerson = numOfPerson ;
      tables = new ArrayList<>() ;
    }
    @Override protected Team clone() {
      return new Team(idx, numOfPerson) ;
    }
    @Override public int compareTo(Team team) {
      return toString().compareTo(team.toString()) ;
    }
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("g(%d:%d),%s", idx+1, numOfPerson, tables) ;
    }
  }
  static class Allotment implements Comparable<Allotment> {
    TreeSet<Team> teams ;
    int score ;
    Allotment() {
      teams = new TreeSet<>() ;
    }
    @Override public int compareTo(Allotment team) {
      return toString().compareTo(team.toString()) ;
    }
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("%6d, %s", score, teams) ;
    }
  }

  TableAllotment(Integer[] tables, Integer[] teams, int x, int y) {
    var tableList = new ArrayList<Table>() ;     // initialize Table list with num of seat
    for (int i = 0 ; i < tables.length ; i++) {
      tableList.add(new Table(i, tables[i])) ;
    }
    var tableAnyOrderSeq = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Table>>() ; // make random table sequence
    genAllOrderSeq(tableList, 0, tableAnyOrderSeq) ;

    var teamList = new ArrayList<Team>() ;  // initialize Team list with num of person
    for (int i = 0 ; i < teams.length ; i++) {
      teamList.add(new Team(i, teams[i])) ;
    }

    var results = new TreeSet<Allotment>() ;
    calcByOrder(tableAnyOrderSeq, teamList, x, y, results) ;
    System.out.println("Team arrival order by input :") ;
    for (Allotment allocment : results) System.out.println(allocment) ;

    // var teamAnyOrderSeq = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Team>>() ;  // make random Team order sequence
    // genAllOrderSeq(teamList, 0, teamAnyOrderSeq) ;
    // results = new TreeSet<Allotment>() ;
    // calcByRandomOrder(tableAnyOrderSeq, teamAnyOrderSeq, x, y, results) ;
    // System.out.println("Team arrival order by random :") ;
    // for (Allotment allocment : results) System.out.println(allocment) ;
  }

  static void calcByOrder(List<ArrayList<Table>> tablesAnyOrder, ArrayList<Team> teams, 
                          int x, int y, TreeSet<Allotment> results) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < tablesAnyOrder.size(); i++) {
      var tables = tablesAnyOrder.get(i) ;
      var remainPerson = -1 ;
      var teamIdx = -1 ;
      var result = new Allotment() ;
      Team team = new Team(-1,-1) ; // dummy initialize
      for (int j = 0 ; j < tables.size(); j++) {
        if (remainPerson <= 0) { // new Team
          if (++teamIdx >= teams.size()) break ;
          team = teams.get(teamIdx).clone() ;
          remainPerson = team.numOfPerson ;
        }
        remainPerson -= tables.get(j).numOfSeat ;
        team.tables.add(tables.get(j)) ;
        if (remainPerson <= 0) {
          Collections.sort(team.tables, (t1, t2) -> t1.idx==t2.idx ? 0 : t1.idx>t2.idx ? 1 : -1) ;
          result.teams.add(team) ;
        }
      }
      if (result.teams.size() > 0) {
        for (Team team_ : result.teams) { // calc served score
          result.score += (team_.tables.size() - 1) * y ;
        }
        for (int k = 0 ; k < teams.size() ; k++) { // find not served teams
          var isServed = false ;
          for (Team team__ : result.teams) {
            if (teams.get(k).idx == team__.idx) {
              isServed = true ;
              break ;
            }
          }
          if (!isServed) result.score += teams.get(k).numOfPerson * x ; // calc not served score
        }
        results.add(result) ;
      }
    }
  }

  // static void calcByRandomOrder(List<ArrayList<Table>> tablesAnyOrder, List<ArrayList<Team>> teamAnyOrder, 
  //                               int x, int y, TreeSet<Allotment> results) {
  //   for (int i = 0 ; i < teamAnyOrder.size(); i++) {
  //     var teams = teamAnyOrder.get(i) ;
  //     calcByOrder(tablesAnyOrder, teams, x, y, results) ;
  //   }
  // }

  static <T> void genAllOrderSeq(List<T> array, int k, List<ArrayList<T>> results) { // generate all order sequence
    for (int i = k; i < array.size(); i++) {
      Collections.swap(array, i, k) ;
      genAllOrderSeq(array, k+1, results) ;
      Collections.swap(array, k, i) ;
    }
    if (k == array.size() -1) results.add(new ArrayList<T>(array)) ;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TableAllotment(new Integer[]{4,5,1,1,1}, new Integer[]{7, 3}, 5, 3) ;
  }
}
```

Result :

```
Team arrival order by input :
     6, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(3:1), t(4:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4)]]
     6, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(3:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4)]]
     6, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(4:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5)], g(2:3),[t(3:1), t(4:1), t(5:1)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(3:1), t(4:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(2:5)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(3:1), t(4:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(3:1), t(4:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4), t(5:1)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(3:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4), t(4:1)]]
     9, [g(1:7),[t(2:5), t(4:1), t(5:1)], g(2:3),[t(1:4), t(3:1)]]
    21, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(3:1)]]
    21, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(4:1)]]
    21, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(5:1)]]
    24, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(3:1), t(4:1)]]
    24, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(3:1), t(5:1)]]
    24, [g(1:7),[t(1:4), t(2:5), t(4:1), t(5:1)]]
```

results are sorted by cost.

- first group can sit at 2nd, 3rd, 4th tables.
- first group can sit at 2nd, 3rd, 5th tables.
- first group can sit at 2nd, 4th, 5th tables.
- second group sits at the first table.

the cost are 6 also.

playground : https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/cGSZq2NIbRxm